# Usability of Chat Icons in Bottom Right of Websites

Tags: chat

Thoughts on the usability of chat icons in the bottom right of web pages. This seems to be the norm.

Should they always be present?

Or if you have a support page, have a link for live chat and then display the chat icon? These seem to always be anchored to the footer to the far right corner.

Other work arounds to show these icons when needed?

Answer (score 1):

There are times when escaping from the standardized beyond an aesthetic option becomes a perception problem. Anyway, the UX design, contrary to the standard graphic design, allows redundancy and is even favored. In this case, both the live chat icon and the link on the same page, are useful and sometimes necessary.

> Two common reasons for which people ignore floating life chat buttons, in general, are:
>  1. They are placed in other position than the standard one
>    (bottom
> right corner of the page)
>  2. They don’t stand out enough relative to the rest of the page.

<sub>*From [The User Experience of Customer-Service Chat Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chat-ux/)*</sub>